# Unable to supply macro name to edit-kbd-macro when M-x is bound to smex

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-macros

When I `M-x edit-kbd-macro`, it prompts saying:

> Keyboard macro to edit (C-x e, M-x, C-h l, or keys):

Here, I would hit `M-x`. It will then allow me to enter the name of the macro. I have several named macros `(fset 'macro-name ...)` entries in my `~/.emacs` file and I can select the one I want to edit.

But when I have:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'smex)
```

in my `~/.emacs`, when I do `M-x edit-kbd-macro` and hit M-x to start selecting a name, it produces an error.

How do I resolve the conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguably this is a bug in `edit-kbd-macro`: it prompts for `M-x` but it checks for something bound to `execute-extended-command`.  An easy workaround is to give some other key sequence bound to `execute-extended-command` instead of `M-x`.  By default, you could use the [Menu Key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) for that.

As of Emacs 26 (where [Bug#29399](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=29399) is fixed) it will work properly if you use **remap** to bind `smex`:

```el
(define-key global-map [remap execute-extended-command] 'smex)
```

Comment: Thanks. That is elaborate. Although I did not understand it, not being an expert in emacs. However, to solve my problem, I did something simpler. I changed the 'smex line in `~/.emacs` to `(global-set-key (kbd "M-]") 'smex)`. But if this is a bug, do developers watch this forum?

Comment: Don't count on developers watching SE.emacs and determining what needs to be done. Use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to report a problem or suggest an enhancement.

Comment: I submitted bug #[29399](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=29399) for this.

Comment: @deshmukh The code was just to point out the problem, I've removed it since it doesn't really help answer the question.

Comment: @npostavs Unfortunately, my keyboard does not have a Menu key. So, I resorted to using `M-]`

Answer (score 0):

Giving a "name" to a keyboard macro defines the macro as the `symbol-function` for the symbol that has that name as its `symbol-name`.  In other words, the name you provide names a **command**.

What do you mean by "*when I try to name a macro using `M-x`*"? Just what did you do?

It doesn't sound like you just provided `M-x` as the name of your keyboard macro.  There's no problem doing that.  That defines a **symbol** `M-x`, giving it a `symbol-function` value that is the macro.  So you can then do `M-x M-x` to run the macro. Or you can then bind that command, `M-x` to a key.

But if you don't bind your command `M-x` to a key then the **key** `M-x` is still bound to command `smex`.

So it's not clear just what you tried to do.

Here is what `C-h k C-x C-k n` says, BTW:

> **`C-x C-k n`** runs the command `kmacro-name-last-macro`, which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in `kmacro.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x C-k n`.
>
> `(kmacro-name-last-macro SYMBOL)`
>
> Assign a name to the last keyboard macro defined.
>
> Argument `SYMBOL` is the name to define.
>
> The **symbol's function definition becomes the keyboard macro string.**
>   Such a "function" cannot be called from Lisp, but it is a valid editor command.

Note the last sentence, in case your problem was that you were trying to call it from Lisp.

Comment: Thanks. That was very detailed. I have edited the question. My problem is reproducible thus. (a) Have `(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'smex)` in `~/.emacs`. (b) have some named keyboard macros also in `~/.emacs` (c) `edit-kbd-macro` and at the prompt, (d) `M-x` to supply name of the macro to edit. It will produce an error saying: Key sequence M-x is not a keyboard macro. Remove the global-key-set from ~/.emacs, restart emacs and now there is no error.